# method storing subclass pointers

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have superclass `A` and subclasses `B` and `C`,

I have to satisfy sort of an interface in a sense that I want to do something like this:

```
x.Add(B());
```

or

```
x.Add(C());
```

or any other subclass of an A.
where `B()` and `C()` are default construtors 
my Add method looks like this:

```
Add(A & data){
vector<A*> vec;
vec.push_back(new A())
}`
```

its giving me an error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘A&’ from an rvalue of type ‘A’`

What is the problem here?

Comment: `data` doesn't be used in `Add` at all. How will you use it?

Comment: how should i use it? like vec.pushback(new A(data))?

Comment: The compiler error is very clear. `A()` produces an rvalue (`A&&`), which you can't bind to a `A&`.

Comment: Make your argument to `Add` a const reference. Also you are pushing back onto a temporary vector, it will be gone when the function returns.

Comment: Are you accustomed to Java or C#, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing temporary objects, which cannot be assigned to a non-const reference.  You would have to make the parameter be a `const` reference instead:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Add(const A &data);

private:
    std::vector<A*> vec;
};

void MyClass::Add(const A &data)
{
    vec.push_back(&data);
}
```

```
MyClass x;
x.Add(B());
x.Add(C());
```

But it does not really make sense to store pointers to temporary objects, since they will be destroyed, leaving the vector holding invalid pointers.

So, one option would be to push caller-allocated pointers instead:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Add(A *data);

private:
    std::vector<A*> vec;
};

void MyClass::Add(A *data)
{
    vec.push_back(data);
}
```

```
MyClass x;
x.Add(new B);
x.Add(new C);
```

But that can cause memory leaks if `vec.push_back()` fails.

Another option is to let `Add()` itself perform the allocation internally, and free it if something goes wrong:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Add()
    {
        std::auto_ptr<T> data(new T);
        vec.push_back(data.get());
        data.release();
    }

private:
    std::vector<A*> vec;
};
```

```
MyClass x;
x.Add<B>();
x.Add<C>();
```